# Get a value from xml file inside a war file without extracting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, war

I want to read a line from a jsp file present in my war file. The path of the jsp file is always the same, so I know where exactly to look for. How do I grep the line from the jsp inside the war file, without extracting the whole war file? I don't want to extract because it would take at least couple of minutes to finish, and I just want to get the version value (1.2.3.210) from that line. This is how the structure looks like -

```
war file name --> final.war 
jsp location inside the war file --> folder1/folder2/version.jsp
line inside the jsp file --> <param><value>version=1.2.3.210</value></param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I did not have to install jar, as it was already available in CentOS

```
jar -xf final.war folder1/folder2/version.jsp
```

Answer (score 2):

A `.war` file is just a zip file, so we can use `unzip` to do what you want. Let's say I have a file `sample.war` with the following content:

```
Archive:  ../sample.war
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      376  07-30-2007 16:26   hello.jsp
        0  07-30-2007 16:26   images/
     1441  07-30-2007 16:26   images/tomcat.gif
      636  07-30-2007 16:26   index.html
        0  07-30-2007 17:18   META-INF/
      106  07-30-2007 17:18   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  07-30-2007 16:26   WEB-INF/
        0  07-30-2007 16:26   WEB-INF/lib/
      813  07-30-2007 16:26   WEB-INF/web.xml
        0  07-30-2007 16:26   WEB-INF/classes/
        0  07-30-2007 16:26   WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/
     1480  07-30-2007 16:26   WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/Hello.class
---------                     -------
     4852                     12 files
```

I can use `unzip` to extract the file `index.html` to stdout like this:

```
unzip -p sample.war index.html
```

To get a particular line from the output, you can just pipe it into `sed`. For example, to extract the line containing `<title>`:

```
$ unzip -p sample.war index.html | sed -n '/<title>/p'
<title>Sample "Hello, World" Application</title>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using unzip? I'm on centos7, so unzip is not available, and I don't want to install it either..

Comment: I'm on CentOS also. I'm not sure what your aversion is to installing `unzip`; it's a standard package. That would be `yum install unzip`. I don't know of any other tools that can extract to `stdout` like this (e.g., I don't think `jar` can do this, although you could extract the file to disk and operate on it).